# How to terminate function execution on catch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

How to terminate function execution on catch? I assume that return should be put where I put it (`.catch( error => {console.log(error);} return)`), but that doesn't work. Tell me how to do it right?

```
    getCustomers: function () {
            let url = '/crm/customer/';

            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                this.customers = response.data.results;
                if (this.customers.length === 100) {
                    for (let i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
                        axios.get('/crm/customer/?page=' + i).then((response) => {
                            this.c = response.data.results;
                            for (let item of this.c.values()) {
                                this.customers.push(item);
                            }
                        }).catch( global_waiting_stop());

                    }
                }
            }).catch( error => { console.log(error); })
            .finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
        },
```

Comment: If I get your question correctly you want if second axios fail just quit ? then wrap those in Promise.all and chain it

Comment: @AniketJha execuse me, but how to do this? I am a beginner

Comment: @AniketJha - Promise.all will still run them concurrently. He would need to convert it to an async function and await each call.... but 97 ajax calls in a row.. that would take a really long time. Surely the API has some kind of paging mechanism to they're not completely guessing like this.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Is it possible to somehow know in advance how many pages a get can be made? I do all this just to get data from all pages, I put 100 with a margin, since new ones will be added

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. first of all your username is awesome.
And yes Promise.all will make many network calls at once, and yes at API level there should be some pagination mechanism to limit call. 
I would have fired page api call wait for data then issue new call. Ekzo is it really required to have page data at the very point?

Comment: @Aniket Jha,  yes i need to get all api data and stuff it into an array

Comment: @Ekzo - Usually for paginated data there should be a "total pages" parameter telling how many pages there are. Can you post an example of the response data?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. why I can't do something like this? What am I doing wrong? I updated the question

Comment: @Ekzo - Please don't edit the code in the question. The answers here are all referring to that code, if you change it the answers are no longer relevant. Making a request to the same endpoint 3 times is a code smell. I told you I'd help you if you can show us wht the server s returning. without that I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. it returns an array of this values: {
            "id": 4206,
            "sap": "137626",
            "sap_be": "BE/137626",
            "name": "ООО \"Профит-Лига СП\"",
            "name_en": "OOO \"Profit-Liga SP\""
        },

Comment: @Ekzo - that doesn't help me. I need the entire response from the server. That's only part of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220630/discussion-between-ekzo-and-i-wrestled-a-bear-once).

Answer (score 2):

[`finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) executes after both the `then` and the `catch` functions. If you don't want it to run then move your `global_waiting_stop` to the bottom of the `then` block instead and get rid of `finally`.

```
getCustomers: function() {
  let url = '/crm/customer/';
  axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    this.customers = response.data.results;
    if (this.customers.length === 100) {
      for (let i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        axios.get('/crm/customer/?page=' + i).then((response) => {
            this.c = response.data.results;
            for (let item of this.c.values()) {
              this.customers.push(item);
            }
          }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            }
            return)
          .finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
      }
    }
    global_waiting_stop();
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
},
```

Comment: I want the entire function to terminate when get (second) crashes. I need to do this? I updated the question

Comment: The issue with that is, you've got a loop in there that's firing off multiple asynchronous tasks all at once. If one of them crashes the other ones are still going to finish. If you want to be able to cancel them you need to do them one at a time and wait for the responses before sending more.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
getCustomers: function() {
    let url = '/crm/customer/';
    return axios.get(url).then((response) => {
       this.customers = response.data.results;
       if (this.customers.length === 100) {
          for (let i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
            return axios.get('/crm/customer/?page=' + i).then((response) => {
              this.c = response.data.results;
                for (let item of this.c.values()) {
                  this.customers.push(item);
                }
              }).catch(error => {
                  console.log(error);
                  return false;
              })
          }
        }
     }).catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
     return false;
   })
},
```

Comment: for doesn't run a second time even though on page 3 I have data :(

Comment: IDE say to me that " 'for' statement doesn't loop"